# iOS swift pull to refresh mixes with tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uirefreshcontrol

In my table view controller, i have implemented pull to refresh (UIRefreshControl). The problem is that I do not know why it is mix with the tableView (UITableViewController). For details, see the screenshot. Thank you for your assistance!

[image: pull to refresh mix with tableView]

Comment: You'll need to provide more detail (code where you're adding the refresh control etc)

Comment: Its happens when i go to another controller, and return back

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to set up the refresh control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement refresh control like this.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    var refreshControl : UIRefreshControl!

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    self.refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    self.refreshControl.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    self.refreshControl.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()

    self.refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: "methodPullToRefresh:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged) 

    self.tableView.addSubview(self.refreshControl)

}

func methodPullToRefresh(sender:AnyObject)
{
    self.refreshControl?.beginRefreshing()

}
```

[image]

```
// Once you are done with your task
self.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()

// Main queue thread is only required when refresh controls comes or goes off with delay, if it works quickly then no need to add this
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

}
```

[image]

Hope, this will resolve your problem.

All the best.

Comment: please check this question --> https://stackoverflow.com/q/67056902/15466427

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I solved it so:

When adding Refresh Controller on View Controller it is necessary to write the following code:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.refreshControl.beginRefreshing()
    self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}
```

Comment: Honestly, I've never used these lines of code in my life